# Pagination manipulated with jquery on CI working, but the link is updated

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pagination

I have one page on html, named view_closing.php. In this view, There is one table that integrated with one pagination. My goal is, how can I make the table is move to another record without refreshing all the page.So, it still on one address, that is :http://localhost/tresnamuda/control_closing/

I googling for a while, and then I decide to make two view, one view to all page, and one view to just the table that will be requested by ajax.

This is the main page :

```
<div class="row-fluid sortable" id="isi">   
<div class="box span12">
    <div class="box-header">
        <h2><i class="halflings-icon align-justify"></i><span class="break"></span>Data Request</h2>
        <div class="box-icon">
            <a href="#" class="btn-minimize"><i class="halflings-icon chevron-up"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-content" id="things_table">
        <?php $this->load->view('view_closing_table'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is the file 2 named view_closing table

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed" id="table1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>No.  </th>
        <th>No Request</th>
        <th>Keluhan</th>                                            
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
</thead>   
<tbody>
    <?php
    $no = 1;
    foreach ($data_request as $data) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="center"><?php echo $no++ . ". "; ?> </td>

        <td class="sorting1" id='no_request' data-id-reseh="<?php echo $data['id_request']; ?>"><?php echo $data['kode_kantor'] . '/' . $data['kode_departement'] . '/' . date('m', strtotime($data['bulan'])) . '/' . $data['id_request']; ?></td>

        <td class="center" id="description"><?php echo $data['keluhan']; ?></td>                                            

        <!-- update  -->
        <td class="center"><a href="#" id="status" name="status" class="linkStatus" ><span id="st" class="label label-important"><?php echo $data['status_request']; ?> </span></a></td> 

        <!-- Action-action -->
        <td  class="center" width="10px">
            <a class="btn btn-success" >
                <i class="halflings-icon white print" id="print"></i>
                Print
            </a>         
        </td>
    </tr>

    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

To make pagination call using ajax, I create one function using to call all the page and one antoher function to just call the view_table. This is the main pagination on my controller :

```
public function index() {
    $this->show();
}

public function show() {

    if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in') != "logging") {
        redirect('control_auth');
    } else {

        $nama = $this->session->userdata('nama');
        $start_row = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $per_page = 3;

        if (trim($start_row) == '') {
            $start_row = 0;
        };

        $total_rows = $this->model_request->countPerUser($this->session->userdata('nama'));

        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'control_closing/ajax_get_things_table'; //call using ajax
        $config['total_rows'] = $total_rows;
        $config['per_page'] = $per_page;
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination pagination-centered"><ul>';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul></div><!--pagination-->';
        $config['first_link'] = TRUE;
        $config['last_link'] = TRUE;
        $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['prev_link'] = 'Prev';
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
        $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
        $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="'.base_url().'control_closing/ajax_get_things_table/">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $data['pengguna'] = $this->model_user->get_username($this->session->userdata('username'));

        $data['data_request'] = $this->model_request->selectRequestPerUser($nama, $per_page, $start_row);

        $this->load->view('view_closing', $data); // Load all page
    }
}
```

Now, I create another function to calling just the table that refreshing bassed on pagintaion.

The code is like this :

```
public function ajax_get_things_table() {
    if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in') != "logging") {
        redirect('control_auth');
    } else {

        $nama = $this->session->userdata('nama');
        $start_row = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $per_page = 3;

        if (trim($start_row) == '') {
            $start_row = 0;
        };

        $total_rows = $this->model_request->countPerUser($this->session->userdata('nama'));

        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'control_closing/ajax_get_things_table/';
        $config['total_rows'] = $total_rows;
        $config['per_page'] = $per_page;
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination pagination-centered"><ul>';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul></div><!--pagination-->';
        $config['first_link'] = false;
        $config['last_link'] = false;
        $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['prev_link'] = 'Prev';
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
        $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
        $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="'.base_url().'control_closing/ajax_get_things_table/">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $data['nama'] = $this->session->userdata('nama');
        $data['level'] = $this->session->userdata('level');
        $data['pengguna'] = $this->model_user->get_username($this->session->userdata('username'));
        $data['data_request'] = $this->model_request->selectRequestPerUser($nama, $per_page, $start_row);

        $_html = $this->load->view('view_closing_table', $data, TRUE); //Just laod the table
        echo $_html;
    }
}
```

I manipulated the pagination on CI using Jquery. The code is written in one view named view_closing like this :

```
$('.pagination ul li a').live("click", function() {
     var this_url = $(this).attr("href");
     $.post(this_url, {}, function(data) {
     $('#things_table').html(data);
   });
   return false;
});
```

And, thank God, it success. like this :
[image: Please see the address bar and the link]

Now, The new problem is rise : in Action field that named "belum selesai" is not working after pagination is work.
I know, because ajax calling http://localhost/tresnamuda/control_closing/ajax_get_things_table/4. But in link button is href ="#" . So link is not working coz the adress now is :http://localhost/tresnamuda/control_closing/ajax_get_things_table/4/#. But the link on jquery looked like this :

```
$(".linkStatus").click(function() {
var $row = $(this).closest("tr");    // Find row
var text = $row.find("#no_request").text(); // Find text
var status = $row.find("#status").text(); // Find text

var idText = text.substring(10);


var c = confirm("Apakah anda akan menutup request ini ? ");

if (c === true) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url() . 'control_closing/closingRequest/' ?>',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {id: idText},
        success: function(obj) {
            if (obj === "true") {
                $('#isi').unblock();
                location.reload();
            }
        }
    });
} else if (c === false) {
    $('#isi').unblock();
}
```

});

The link just working if the address is : http://localhost/tresnamuda/control_closing/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you're using Ajax to load the page content, then trying to attach an event to it, but you're event is trying to attach before the content is loaded. When the page gets to `$(".linkStatus").click(function() {` it scans the page for all elements with a class of `linkstatus`, but because your content hasn't loaded yet (the Ajax is still loading it) there's no element with that class name, so no events are set up.

What you need to do is either attach the event to something that already exists, like `document`, or attach the event after the page has loaded.

Either of these examples should solve your issue:

**Attach the event to an existing element**

You need to change

```
$(".linkStatus").click(function() {
```

to

```
$(document).on('click', '.linkStatus', function() {
```

**Attach the event after the Ajax has run**

First you need to wrap your event handler in a function, so you can call it.

```
function Start() {
    $(".linkStatus").click(function() {
        //... Code to run when linkStatus is clicked.
    });
}
```

And then in the ajax success function where you're loading the table, at the end of the function add a call to `Start()` to attach your event.